# stuck running playwright test inside docker container during bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, bitbucket, playwright

I have an pipeline on bitbucket that use atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.0 to connect my release server and run cypress tests in docker container.

I would like to convert my pipeline to playwright but when I tried same approach, always stuck on:

```
Installing dependencies...
Switching to root user to install dependencies...
```

Here is my pipeline step:

```
      - step:
          name: Playwright e2e tests
          caches:
            - docker
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.0
              variables:
                SSH_USER: "$RELEASE_SERVER_USER"
                SERVER: "$RELEASE_SERVER_HOST"
                COMMAND: 'make pw-tests'
                PORT: $RELEASE_SERVER_PORT
```

And here is my pw-tests command:

```
pw-tests: ## Runs e2e pw tests
date +"[%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S] Running Playwright e2e tests"
docker run -t --rm \
 -v `pwd`:/app -w /app \
 node:18-alpine \
 npm i && npx playwright install && npx playwright install-deps --dry-run && npx playwright test
```

I'm expecting to run playwright tests successfully.